Should this HTTP contract class be considered a repository, service, or just an HTTP client?
I'm looking for some advice or best practices for a pattern we're discussing internally.
We have a class (example below) that defines an HTTP contract to interact with an external REST API. The class is responsible for making requests to fetch, create, update, and delete user data.
Internally, there’s a debate about whether this should be considered a "repository," a "service," or just an "HTTP client."

Repository? Some argue it could be considered a repository because it
acts as a data access layer for external APIs.

Service? Others believe it should be a service, since it's doing business logic, albeit limited to data manipulation.

HTTP Client? Another perspective is that it’s just an HTTP client
since it’s solely focused on making API calls.


What do you think? How do you classify this pattern in your projects? Are there any best practices or design patterns to consider, especially when using NestJS?
Example class:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

@Injectable()
export class UserApiClient {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

  getUserById(userId: string): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {
    return this.httpService.get(`/users/${userId}`);
  }

  createUser(data: any): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {
    return this.httpService.post('/users', data);
  }

  updateUser(userId: string, data: any): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {
    return this.httpService.put(`/users/${userId}`, data);
  }

  deleteUser(userId: string): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {
    return this.httpService.delete(`/users/${userId}`);
  }
}


I think this is a service, does you guys have a HttpClient use case? Maybe it overlaps NestJS HttpClient concept

I would classify UserApiClient as an HTTP client. It's responsible for interacting with an external API, abstracting the details of HTTP communication. This classification is clear and adheres to good design practices, especially in the context of NestJS where services are expected to handle more than just HTTP requests.
If more complex logic needs to be applied, consider creating a higher-level service that utilizes UserApiClient, but don't mix responsibilities by embedding business logic into the HTTP client itself.
